# Sitecore DMS - Useragents and Operating Systems

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-dms

With Sitecore DMS where/how does it resolve operating system?

I know the user agent will say "Windows NT 5.1" etc but our operating systems table has nothing like this, just WinXP.

Infact the operating system table seems quite outdated for us, how do we add new ones and have them match up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems after digging through code in ILSpy that this just uses the ASP.NET Browser Capabilities:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpbrowsercapabilities.aspx